# Where to keep interfaces in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to both React & Typescript and having an issue with where I keep the interfaces.

I'm received a large JSON object from an api call which I'm using in several components/screens. I've interfaced this returned value correctly however every component that uses this JSON object I have to copy and paste the interface, which doesn't seem like good coding standards.

Where should I keep these interfaces? And how do I reference them in my main file or tsconfig?

Thanks.

Comment: In any file you want. Make sure to export the interface, and import it where you need it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Oh fantastic! I wasn't aware you could export interfaces like that. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are new to React, I recommend starting without typescript, and then implementing it once you understand some of the fundamentals. It helps lessen the learning curve.